# ICY BOX IB-3810U3 10-Bay External - Compatibility

Tags: hard-drive, compatibility

Could anyone confirm whether [ICY BOX IB-3810U3 10-Bay External SINGLE System for 10x SATA 3.5" I/II/III HDD](https://www.raidsonic.de/products/external_cases/external_cases_35/index_en.php?we_objectID=3410) with external USB 3.0 interface and UASP support works with Ubuntu (or even any other Linux)?

On the manufacturer's website it is stated that they support Windows and MAC OS, but we all know how it is - that's the official support. I already asked their support, but received the following response:

*We support Windows and MAC. It might work on Linux. We can’t help.*

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, it should work.

Comment: The Icy Box external devices *usually* present their drives in a JBOD fashion, which Ubuntu can handle. Connecting similar devices to a Raspberry Pi, however, does tend to result in failure. Unfortunately, there are no confirmed reports of this particular device working with any Ubuntu release that I can find.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, commenter IJH on A claims: «You will need to disable UAS on either the host device (or blacklist UAS support for the ASM1051E chip this device uses in Linux) because the UAS support in this hardware is broken and fails badly under load. It seems to work ok in basic usb-storage mode though (though this is slower than UAS, it at least works properly).»

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that it works. I am using a IB-3810-C31 (same as the IB-3810-U3 but with USB 3.1 Gen 2 and USB-C plug) on a Ubuntu 20.04.2 and the 10 drives are appearing individually and can be mounted as I want.